# Walk through dynamically changing folders

Tags: python, dynamic, directory, os.walk

I have implemented os.walk a ton of times until now, and it worked super fine.

But now, I need to implement os.walk on a folder, whose contents keeps on changing/updating every 10 secs (by another program). And, when I do os.walk on this folder, the program gets stuck there forever.

Comment: Why are you walking over changing content? Is this a hard requirement?

Comment: yes sir :)  this folder is located on our NAS and is being hit by many other programs 24/7.

Comment: i was not done writing my comment above (damn 'enter' key :D). So, what I want to add is, I found another way of doing this. Robocopy the files I want to my local machine, and then do the walking. It works fine now, but, would definitely be useful to know how to walk over dynamically changing folder